# WordPress site started automatically redirecting all pages to home -- only works if 'plain' permalinks are selected?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a Wordpress site that uses the 'post name' style permalink: `http://website/sample-post/`. This site has operated like this for nearly 5 years now.

Today, all pages randomly started redirecting to the homepage. In the Firefox network inspector, I can see the request come in which results in a 301 redirect and the next request is to `/`.

My .httaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried removing that HTTP_AUTHORIZATION line but it made no difference. I think I may have added that for Cloudflare purposes a while ago.

If I select 'Plain' style permalink, I can actually access a page without this home redirect. I do not want to use that style as all of my SEO rankings are based on the post name style. Switching back to the post name style does not fix it.

I have tried disabling all plugins as well as updating Wordpress to the latest version. I also updated my plugins. I am using an older version of PHP, but I don't see how that could be the cause as this occurred suddenly.

Comment: Do you use a host that provides excellent technical support? If so, they may be able to answer your question. There could be factors at play that are not included in the information you have.

Comment: Hi @NoraMcDougall-Collins, appreciate you spotting this and chiming in early. I am on the phone with GoDaddy right now -- 41 mins and counting! I do see some other users having issues with .htaccess files in some of the support threads over there, maybe not an isolated incident.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It might fit better on superuser, serverfault, or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I disagree. I mentioned Wordpress for context. This could also be related to something with my PHP configuration or something else that would fit in a 'development' box. I suppose your guess is as good as mine, but I don't think a guess is a good enough reason to close a question.

Comment: That is an interesting line of thought. It is very common to not know where the actual problem lies. I vote for not closing questions where the source might be WordPress to help developers learn to observe the behaviors and determine the source.